# Show that it exists an Unique Linear Map

Tags: linear-algebra, exterior-algebra

Suppose $ A $ is a skew-symmetric matrix with elements in $ \mathbb{R}. $

Show that it exists an Unique linear map $ L$ such that

$$ L: \bigwedge^2 \mathbb{C}^3 \to \mathbb{C} \\ (x \wedge y) \mapsto x^T Ay \quad \forall x,y \in  \mathbb{C}^3. $$

Attempt for solution;

$ ( x \wedge y) $ is bilinear and alternating. Thus, $ (x \wedge y ) = - ( y \wedge x) $, and $ L(x \wedge y) = L(-y \wedge x) $.

I dont know how to show it's an unique map. Does the linearity imply uniqness?

Comment: How did you define $\bigwedge^2$? Some definitions make this easy (e.g. they say "the set of maps $\bigwedge^2 A\rightarrow B$ is in natural bijection with the set of alternating bilinear maps from $A\times A$ to $B$), whereas some are more difficult (e.g. $\bigwedge^2 A$ is some quotient of a free vector space on terms of the form $x\wedge y$)